# How to handle this particular download redirection with Python script to download video?

Tags: python, download, redirect

I want to download the video using python script from this link:
https://www.coursera.org/algo/lecture/download.mp4?lecture_id=4

But I tried many ways, and turn out my Python script can't handle the redirection correctly as my chrome browser does.
My browser can resolve the link to:
http://d19vezwu8eufl6.cloudfront.net/algo1/recoded_videos%2F%5Bfe646c5e%5D%20guiding.mp4
However, the code below can't return correct resource.

Below is the Python code used and borrowed from another topic "python-urllib-urllib2-httplib-confusion" after I tried urlretrieve and other normal ways to download.

```
url = 'https://www.coursera.org/algo/lecture/download.mp4?lecture_id=4'

import cookielib

request = urllib2.Request(url)

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()

cookies.extract_cookies(response,request)

cookie_handler= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor( cookies )

redirect_handler= urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirect_handler,cookie_handler)

response = opener.open(request)

print response.geturl()
```

Comment: Does this Python code account for the authentication?

Comment: Really appreciate. I never thought to log out my account and try.

Comment: For this, try the `mechanize` module. It might be a little overkill, but it automates browser interactions pretty well and is easy to use.

Comment: @Blender can you please explain what you meant when you said accounting for authentication? I am trying the basic authentication using urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm to store passwords and urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler to create a handler to handle the login process but it's not working. Could you suggest some possible method for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/index.html) makes this easier, since it handles redirection, authentication, cookies, etc.

```
import requests
the_url = 'https://www.coursera.org/algo/lecture/download.mp4?lecture_id=4'
username = 'username'
password = 'secret'

r = requests.get(the_url, auth=(username, password))
r.content # your result
```

Comment: how can the above response object be used the download the link? Whenever, I try to retrieve the url using r.url command, all the get is a link which requires the authentication. I should be getting the link of the video but this doesn't seem to be the case. Can you please help?